# Asp.net Mvc 2 + SQL Server Database + Setup Project / Installer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment

Hey everyone, there's one thing bugging me for quite some time now. How can I create a setup project (resulting in a msi package) for my Asp.Net Mvc 2 Project? The installer / msi should create a website in iis7, a database in SQL Server 2008 and put the connection string(s) into the `web.config`. What is the best way to achieve this? Does anyone have experiences with 3th party products or does plain old vs2010 the trick?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you heard of Web Deploy?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't figure out if it is possible to deploy a sql database as well.

Comment: I did some digging and found the following: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/578/package-an-application-for-the-windows-web-application-gallery/ seems to be exactly what I was looking for ... I'm going to check it out today

Comment: Did that work for you? If so, please post as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for iis 7 you can copy(install) the project  quite easy

in your solution select option add new project / other project files/ setup and deployment/ Visual Studio installer.

and in the installer you can define all the definition you need.

this is just basic, as i needed to just install the project to location for administrator. nothing else.

good luck